# How to send data from Activity to View

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

How can I make canvas drawing with custome value.
I used this method to send data from my Information.class extends AppCompatActivity
to CustomeView extends View

Information.class

```
   public int getCategory() {
    int side = 100;
    return side;
}
```

CustomView.class (extends view)

```
Information playObject = new Information();
int passed = playObject.getCategory();
```

and it works, but I want to make "side" to have value of Edittext input.
I tried.

```
String y = et1.getText().toString();
int side = Integer.parseInt(y);
```

but then I got errors with

com.example.solar.Schemat.onCreate

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.solar/com.example.solar.Schemat}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #106: Binary XML file line #106: Error inflating class com.example.solar.views.CustomeView

Comment: show more code, how do you get access to `EditText` inside custom class, its wrong for shure

Comment: why can't you make a variable in your view class and then use findViewById/viewbinding to give it the value ?

Comment: @snachmsm i trying find method to do this i tried
 et1 = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberDecimalTest3);
but when i try prase it to integer to draw circle i got error